# Converting Integer Rows into Columns While Grouping by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following table with these columns TimeStamp[DateTime], FromSysId[Int], CrUSSDCnt[Int]

```
       TimeStamp           FromSysId          CrUSSDCnt
2015-06-18 18:58:15.380        25                 7
2015-06-18 19:45:17.130        21                 8
2015-06-18 20:43:18.920        22                 15
2015-06-18 21:34:33.090        25                 6
2015-06-18 22:55:33.317        22                 10
```

And I want to display each FromSysId as Column while counting the CrUSSDCnt column of each FromSysId and grouping TimeStime by Hour like this output:

```
       TimeStamp         Sys25   Sys22     Sys21       
2015-06-18 18:00:00       2        1         0
2015-06-18 19:00:00       4        6         3
2015-06-18 20:00:00       0        5         6
2015-06-18 21:00:00       0        7         2
2015-06-18 22:00:00       1        0         4
```

I tried using pivot or Joint and i failed both to summarize like this way. 
Any help.

Comment: Please edit your question with your queries that don't work.

Answer (score 1):

The hard part of this problem is extracting the hour from the time.  Here is one method:

```
select dateadd(hour, 0, datediff(hour, 0, timestamp)) as ToTheHour,
       sum(case when FromSysId = 25 then CrUSSDCnt else 0 end) as Sys25,
       sum(case when FromSysId = 22 then CrUSSDCnt else 0 end) as Sys22,
       sum(case when FromSysId = 21 then CrUSSDCnt else 0 end) as Sys21
from table t
group by dateadd(hour, 0, datediff(hour, 0, timestamp))
order by ToTheHour;
```

The rest is just conditional aggregation.

Comment: @AbdallaOmar . . . If you have a question, you should ask it as a *question* not an answer.  Ask another question, if you still need help.